# Will the screw on the quick release plate attach to my camera?

Tags: tripod, tripod-heads

Recently I ordered the tripod Digitek DTR-550 LW on Amazon for my Nikon B700 camera. But I'm not sure that my camera will attach with the screw on quick release mount of the tripod. Please throw some light upon this confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will. There are only two screw sizes: small (1/4") and big (3/8"). Light camera (and this includes DSLRs...) use the small screw thread, and all the quick-release plates I have encountered also use the small thread.

I have only seen the big thread used to join tripod parts (tripod to ball head, for instance).